# capturing pressed keys in c++ windows application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

i would like to know which keys are pressed in my c++/windows application.

what should i put inside `WM_KEYDOWN`?

```
switch (message)
    {
       case WM_KEYDOWN:
           // for example, what should i write to know if "F" key was pressed?
    }
```

thank you!

Comment: Please RTFM - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: there are no actual character keys there, just stuff like enter or tab

Comment: i need character keys like A or B

Comment: scroll this page down - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: oops my fault, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try folloiwng:

```
switch (message)
{
  case WM_KEYDOWN:
    switch (wParam) 
    {
      // ...
      case 'F': DoSomething(); break;
      // ...
      case VK_RETURN: DoSomethingElse(); break;
      // ...
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: rica ederim :) eger isini cozduyse cevabi onaylamayi unutmazsan sevinirim :)

Comment: bekleme suresi varda o yuzden basamadim

Comment: Note that if you are interested in responding to typing, you should use `WM_CHAR` rather than `WM_KEYDOWN`. That way you will capture the F even if it is typed via an IME or Alt+070.

Comment: Also, WM_KEYDOWN gives you 'F' regardless of shift key state. If you care about F vs f - or 4 vs $ (both are the 4 key on a US keyboard), then use WM_CHAR instead. A good rule of thumb is to use WM_CHAR for anything that's textual input, and WM_KEYDOWN for non-text keys, like the arrowkeys, home, end, and so on.